# SQL 2008 SP2 RsClientPrint ActiveX - "Unable to load client print control"

Tags: sql-server-2008

We recently updated our SQL 2008 server to use SP 2 and its causing a few headaches. We use SSRS on this server and when a client tries to print a report by the built-in print function, we're needing to download the RsClientPrint ActiveX control from the server from the client gets the following error **Unable to load client print control**.

We have about 700 computers that are needing this fixed and I've followed the instructions found on the following URL: http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/client-side-printing-silent-deployment-of-rsclientPrint.aspx

We have two issues:

1. Most of the users who will be using this ActiveX control are **not** local administrators so they will not be able to install the control themselves
2. Since there are so many computers, this has to be done silently behind the scenes run by a local admin account

After following the information from the link above, we're able to put the files in the C:\Windows\System32 folder and register the DLL but we still get the same problem. The only small thing I've noticed is that in the HTML for the report page, everything that references a version is referencing version 2007.100.4000.00 and the version of the DLL that I pulled from the report server is 2007.100.1600.22.

Also, for some clients that are local administrators, they are prompted every time to install the ActiveX control when they click print. This works successfully but we can't have the user asked if they want to install the same control every time they need to print.

Comment: Well, I found the solution but I don't have enough points yet to submit the answer. The fix is that Microsoft had a bug in the SP2 release and you need to download the latest SP2 cumulative update from them and it will update the reference of the RsClientPrint.CAB file on the SSRS server

Comment: A similar problem is still occurring with SQL Server 2008 R2 reporting services with no updates.  Reporting Services is asking for a CAB matching the Server revision Version=2009,100,1617,00 but the distributed CAB is version 2009,100,1600,1.  On Windows 7 with UAC enabled, the print control loads, but attempts to elevate to install a newer version on every print. Fixed by installing newer CABs:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/fef335e9-c345-4c8e-a105-e52e31ffbf36/#e90bab71-8aae-496f-a1bc-0f79cc3ad333

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem where users were being asked to install the ActiveX control every time they printed the report. This appears to be a problem peculiar to version 2007.100.1600.22 of the RsClientPrint addon.

Installing Cumulative Update 4 didn't update the version of RsClientPrint, so I replaced the 3 cab files with those from a 2008 R2 report server (v2009.100.160.1), deleted the rsclientprint.* files from the client machines and it all seems to work now.